# Were there any notable historic figures that weren't racist by modern standards?

Tags: racism

With all this talk of Confederate monuments, I started wondering if there was anyone in history that couldn't be considered racist by some modern standard.

I understand many historical figures didn't speak on race, so I would limit this question to people who, in some way or another, espoused views on race that would be considered in-line with a modern, progressive viewpoint (or close to it).

Put another way, a person who could be plucked from history and brought to the 20th century without any worry about them having controversial views. They might even rejoice at how far society had progressed (relatively speaking).

For example, Abraham Lincoln is often remembered as the president who freed the slaves. However, if we brought him to the present, some of his remarks in the past suggest he would disagree with certain policies regarding racial equality, discrimination, etc.

I guess I'll limit this to racism, but if the person was also progressive regarding other forms of discrimination (sex, gender, sexual orientation, etc.) that would be a bonus. For the time, I think pre-1900 would be a minimum, but the further back the better.

Edit: I guess I should also limit this to individuals that weren't part of an oppressed population in their society, or there will probably be a lot more answers.

Edit 2: I realize this is kind of a vague question. I've just been tired of hearing the old "you can't judge them by modern standards" and was hoping to hear some good counter examples.

Comment: I guess that [William Wilberforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Wilberforce) might meet your criteria. He has statues in Kingston-upon-Hull (his birthplace) and [Westminster Abbey](http://www.westminster-abbey.org/our-history/people/william-wilberforce). I'm not aware of any current plans to tear them down.

Comment: Even Robert E Lee himself want racist. He didn't keep black slaves because he thought black people were somehow inferior, he did so because he thought it ws God's will to have slavery. A lot of bad things are done for good reasons

Comment: This is certainly at risk of the absence of evidence being taken as evidence of absence. Lack of any record isn't proof that they wouldn't be considered racist (or sexist or homophobic, etc.) by modern standards.

Comment: @Charlie: You might also reflect that slavery had been the norm for all of human history.

Comment: @Charlie - That would be like arguing a European monarchist reactionary (eg: a [Cavalier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalier)) wasn't an elitist oppressor, but was just supporting "The Divine Right of Kings" because they were religious. It's just modern apologetics, not legit historical analysis.

Comment: @Charlie - The most obvious counter in Lee's case is the instance where as an executor of a will that clearly emancipated all the slaves, he went to court and got a 5 year stay (and kept them all every minute of those 5 years). But really the claim of him not being a supremacist is modern balderdash that doesn't stand up to even a cursory examination of the life of the man.

Comment: I'm going to have to downvote for your edit - the notion that members of minorities are automatically absolved of racism flies in the face of history. African Americans and Irish Americans had a fine tradition of contempt for one another.  There are several minority religions that have startlingly racist views.

Comment: You would have a lot of trouble arguing that Karl Marx was a racist.

Comment: Robert E. Lee was offered position as General of the Union Army by Lincoln but he turned it down because he wasn't comfortable fighting against his fellow Virginians.

Comment: Marx's essay [*On the Jewish question*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Jewish_Question) is often interpreted as antisemitic.

Comment: @Philipp. I assume you know that Marx was a Jew.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Looking at the answers and comments present right now, your comment on Alex's answer is possibly the best throughout this entire topic. Might you consider putting it is a separate answer?

Comment: "You might also reflect that slavery had been the norm for all of human history". This is nonense. From all we know, for millions of years humans did not know such things. Pls. turn to work from paleo-anthropology and ethno-archeology for a primer on human development, and archeology and prehistory for any hints to such habits. Until clear findings to the contrary, social stratification comes with division of work and settledness.

Comment: @gktscrk I don't think my comment really answers this question. Furthermore, it is IMHO *a question that should not be answered*. I have a personal belief that *people* aren't racist, only their actions. We *all* have evil and good in us, and that evil certainly includes racism. Nobody is 100% anything. Of course some folks habitually let their actions be dominated by their racism, so perhaps calling them "racist" as a person is fair. But its still at best just a shortcut to saying they are prone to racist words and actions.

Comment: @T.E.D.: Perhaps the best "anti-answer" is what I should have called it as you did describe what you said above, though more concisely—in any case, I'm in agreement.

Answer (score 3):

There were many. Quaker leaders for one. How about [Frederick Douglass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Douglass)?

Comment: I think that Frederick Douglass would fail under the criteria imposed by the OP's edit addition "_limit this to individuals that weren't part of an oppressed population in their society_".  Good choice otherwise though.

Comment: @sempaiscuba - If the question were "bigoted", I'd still give it to this answer because he fought to [give women the vote](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederick_Douglass#Women.27s_rights) as well.

Comment: @T.E.D. I'd agree, except that OP also limited the question to racism, rather than wider questions of prejudice. But I do know about Frederick Douglass. That's why I said he's a good choice otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

This is a meaningless question unless you focus on some period in history. Racism is a relatively modern invention. Almost any person before 16 century would have a clean record in this respect by modern standards.

Comment: Clarifying a bit. Human beings have pattern-matching brains, so judging someone based on looks is probably as old as our species. However, the concept of "race" as thing separate from culture, and being transmitted inerrently through bloodlines forever, is a very European thing. Your typical tribal society has no compunction about adopting people from other cultures who honestly want to join. For example, the main [Cherokee chief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Ross_(Cherokee_chief)#Genealogy) on the Trail of Tears was 7/8ths Scotts (and had red hair).

Comment: I agree with your comment, but want to emphasize that this is a LATE European invention.

Comment: I am not sure why you put the borderline in the 16th century. In pre-modern Europe people classified themselves and others mainly on the basis of religion. It is not really until the 19th century that "race" replaces religion as the basis for classification of individuals and societies.

Comment: @fdb: you are right. I choose 16 century, just to be on the "safe side".